# select and return an array of selected files in elfinder

Tags: javascript, php, elfinder

I'm using [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) file manager. that is great and easy to use.

that has multi select files capability . but I want to use it for select some files then by pressing `enter` keyboard button, path of those files Be returned as an Javascript Array.

This is My code to initialize elFinder instance :

```
$('.add-item').on('click', function () {

    var filesArr = [];

    $('<div id="editor" />').dialogelfinder({
        url: './elfinder/php/connector.minimal.php',
        getFileCallback: function (file) {
            $('#editor').dialogelfinder('close');
            console.log(file.url);
        }
    });


});
```

that works when select one file but when user select multi files and press `enter`, all selected files opens for preview only.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure behaviour of *getFileCallback* with '[*commandsOptions*](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#commandsOptions)'. In your case you need to alter *multiple* property and set it to true

```
commandsOptions : {
     getfile: {
        multiple: true
     }
}
```