# Select multiples files using checkbox el finder

Tags: elfinder

I use Elfinder , to display multiple files, I need to select multiple files in the same time using checkbox for every file
here is my code

```
elFinder.prototype.options = {
commandsOptions : {
            getfile : {
                onlyURL  : false,
                multiple : true, 

                folders  : true,
                oncomplete : ''
            }
      }
}
```

is there any option that allow to add a `checkbox` for every file? and how can i get Selected files,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959598/select-and-return-an-array-of-selected-files-in-elfinder

If not, please provide further details. Providing existing code is a big help.

Comment: I saw this poste but what i need is  to add a checkbox next to each file, i have added this option lFinder.prototype.options = { commandsOptions : {
   // "getfile" command options.
   getfile : {
    onlyURL  : false,
    // allow to return multiple files info
    multiple : true,
    // allow to return filers info
    folders  : true,
    // action after callback (""/"close"/"destroy")
    oncomplete : ''
   },  }      but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you put all that in the question with any context code? It'll be easier to read formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `uiOptions.cwd.showSelectCheckboxUA`.

And `getFileCallback` is an option to get selected files info.

```
uiOptions: {
    cwd: {
        showSelectCheckboxUA: ['all']
    }
},
getFileCallback: function(data, fm) {
    fm.log(data); // to show data into browser console
}
```

Comment: i have added it but nothing appears in elfinderComponennt , do i have to add something it else ?,